# Is there a way to run Trac offline?

Tags: bug-tracking, trac, offline, issue-tracking

I'd like to download the [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) database so I can view its tickets offline. Is there anyway to achieve this? I.e. if I need to leave the office and bring my laptop with me, how can I bring the tickets with me without having to connect to the company network?

I know that [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) can download and sync tickets via it's trac connector but I'd like some stand-alone viewer.

Comment: Do you have access to the server trac database? Obviously, if so, you could `mysqldump` the server database to a trac installation on your workstation. Please clarify.

Comment: @Elazar Leibovich: Yes, I have but dumping the database and installing trac on my local workstation/laptop is a suboptimal solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Simple Defects (SD)](http://syncwith.us/sd/).

I particularly like the "One-tweet install" idea.

```
I’m installing #SD (http://syncwith.us) 
after reading about it on #StackOverflow
curl fsck.com/sd|perl; 
export $PATH=~/sd/bin:$PATH; sd
```

Note that you can [clone Trac (and other bugtrackers) in SD](http://syncwith.us/sd/using/#sharingticketdatabases):

```
sd clone --from trac:https://trac.parrot.org/parrot
```

Comment: Ah! Reading through the doc reveals that SD can clone and sync with Trac and other issue tracking systems (at the time of writing RT, Hiveminder, Google Code, Github). Redmine is readonly at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as you don't want to install a server, how about using RSS? IIRC, Trac let lets you get RSS feeds for each person, so you can have a feed of things assigned to you.

All you need do then is get a nice client that will download these tickets. You should be able to access a plaintext version without internet connection.

If that's not flexible enough, you could write a script on the server to publish a feed using the database directly.

And if RSS isn't for you (and your email is available offline), you could mail reports home. Trac also has this built in.

Answer (score 2):

The default Trac installation uses a combination of SQLite to matintain all of the data. Attachements are stored on the file system.

In the folder containing the trac site, find \db\trac.db

This file can be viewed using the [SQLite manager Firefox Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817)

Happy hunting.

Answer (score 1):

And if RSS or email isn't your notification of choice, there's a trac plugin that will let you receive task notifications on your [Remember The Milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com) todo list.

See: http://1.www.rememberthemilk.com/forums/ideas/3580/?forum=ideas&hl=bs&topic=3580

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is simply to **view** the tickets offline, how about

1. Run a report with all the tickets (or all those you're interested in).
2. Select either the comma-delimited or tab-delimited download link at the bottom of the page.
3. Import the downloaded file into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

you could install it on a local machine

Answer (score 0):

You can host the trac locally and set up the connectionstring point to your dowloaded database.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Install a web server locally, install trac, get it set up the same (or similar) way to the way it is on the live version and then script the server to publish db backups and write a local script to download those and restore them over your database.

It's not simple (installing Trac is a battle on its own from my experience of it) but every element is highly googleable =)

Comment: I've installed Trac on a server, but I'd rather not install web server and trac on my windows laptop. :) I'd like some nice stand-alone way to bring my tasks with me without having to print them out seperately.

Answer (score 0):

The trac client FatBug (http://fat-bug.com/) listed in 
https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/Clients
seems to do the exact what was described by the OP. I bumped into it after I just checked SD. SD seems trival on Linux, but heavy on Windows, it depends on Perl & CPAN.